# Java stream: Generate objects directly from an input file and save the objects with Spring Data

Tags: spring, java-8, stream, spring-data

I'll generate for each line from an input file a Foo object and save in the next step all the objects in the database (Spring Data JPA).

```
    //read file into stream
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines((path), Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"))) {

        Stream<Foo> rStream = stream.map(line -> new Foo(line));           
        rStream.forEach(line -> fooRepository.save(line));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I received an `Unhandled exception: java.lang.Exception`, because the constructor of the Foo class can propagate an exception from the MyParser class:

```
public Foo(String row) throws Exception {
        String split[] = StringUtils.split(row, "Ú");
        field    =   MyParser.getInt(split[0]);
}
```

Is it possible to use the Java stream API anyway? Maybe with only one awesome stream? Somethings like this:

```
stream.map(Foo::new).forEach(foo -> fooRepository.save(foo));
```

I use Java 8 with Spring Boot 1.5.8.

Comment: `throws Exception`? Serves you right for creating an API that to all intents and purposes is unusable. What do you expect people to do with the information that `new Foo` can throw **absolutely any** `Exception`? How should a consumer of the API handle this amazingly useful tidbit?

Comment: @BoristheSpider `amazing useful tidbit` :) plus one!

Comment: Also, this should be `stream.map(Foo::new).forEach(fooRepository::save)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can edit the class, why not simply throw a `RuntimeException` instead of throwing an `Exception`. If the API that you use still throws `Exception` you can just wrap it into:

```
catch(Exception e){
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Then you can simplify it to :

```
 stream.map(Foo::new).forEach(fooRepository::save)
```